# Cant change color of validator (RequiredFieldValidator) JavaFX (JFoenix)

Tags: css, validation, javafx, fxml, jfoenix

Please, help me change color of validator
this advice didn't help me :

```
.error * {
  -fx-text-fill: someColor;
}
```

and this just change color of prompt text:

```
-fx-prompt-text-fill: yourcolor;
```

Also, I treid this:
(fxml)

```
<JFXTextField fx:id="usernameText" labelFloat="true" minWidth="220" promptText="%login.label" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" styleClass="input">
    <validators>
        <RequiredFieldValidator message="Необходимо ввести имя пользователя" style="-fx-text-fill: red">
        </RequiredFieldValidator>
    </validators>
</JFXTextField>
```

or set `styleClass="myClass"` or through `id="validator"`; And describe class/id in my .css-file
(i.css file hasn't problem)

Also I treid set style in my Controller (on groovy)

```
validator.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red")
```

or

```
validator.getStyleClass().add("validator")
```

or

```
validator.setId("validator")
```

But all without success

My validator-code:

```
RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator()   
usernameText.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
        void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (!newValue) {
                usernameText.validate()
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question

You can use the tool ScenicView in order to determine to which CSS-class the object belongs.

In my case this is

```
.error-label {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size: 8pt;
}
```

It's fix my problem

[image]

Comment: This helped. Thank you.